# How to play outgoing dialler tone in outgoing call in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, opentok, callkit

I'm using opentok to create app to app voice/video calls. I've also implemented callkit, however, is there any way by which I can play dialler tone while making outgoing call just like what we have in normal calling apps.
I've customized provider configuration in callkit

```
 providerConfiguration.ringtoneSound = "Ringtone.caf"
```

However, this only works during incoming call as a normal ringtone, not a dialler tune

Answer (score 3):

You can play your on audio as dialler tone, while making voip call using AVFoundation.

```
var url = URL_OF_YOUR_RINGTONE_FILE
var player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
var doSetProperty = UInt32(true)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)  AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, MemoryLayout<doSetProperty>.size, doSetProperty)
player?.numberOfLoops = -1
player?.play()
```